# How to delate tableview cell from button options in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, popover

I am able to delete tableview cell when button click..

but now i need to delete tableview cell from button options click like below image [image how button shows options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cM2r.png)

in the above image if i click button i showing one `PopoverView` in that if i click delete then that tableview cell should delete, how to do that?

code: if i do like below.. when i click on dots button then only cell is deleteing.. but i want when i click button popoverview should display from that if i select delete then cell to be delete? how to do?

```
@objc func deleteService(sender:UIButton){
    
    let servId = servicesArray[sender.tag].id
    let param = ["service_id" : servId]
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param as [String : Any], method: .post, loaderNeed: false, loadingButton: nil, needViewHideShowAfterLoading: nil, vc: self, url: CommonUrl.remove_requests, isTokenNeeded: true, isErrorAlertNeeded: true, isSuccessAlertNeeded: false, actionErrorOrSuccess: nil, fromLoginPageCallBack: nil) { [weak self] (resp) in
            if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
                let success = code["status"] as? [String : Any]
                let message = success?["message"] as? String
                if message == "Success"{
                    let selectedIndex = sender.tag
                    self?.servicesArray.remove(at: selectedIndex)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self?.servicesTableView.reloadData()
                     }
                }
            }else{
                self?.view.makeToast(CommonMessages.somethingWentWrong)
            }
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServicesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ServicesTableViewCell
   
    cell.optionsBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.optionsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteService(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

to show `popover`:

```
extension PageContentViewController: PopoverViewDelegate {
func value(didSelect item: String, at index: Int, indexPath: IndexPath, sender: UIView) {
    if item == "View" {
        let vc = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .ViewRequestDetailsViewController, StoryBoardName: .Requests) as! ViewRequestDetailsViewController
       self.checkAndPushPop(vc, navigationController: self.navigationController)
    } 
else if item == "Edit" {
    }else if item == "Delete" {
    // if i click delete i need to delete tableview cell
    }
}
}
```

if i click button popover is coming but if click delete from popover i need to delete cell, how?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the item you want to delete from the tableView's data sources array first like so:

```
self?.servicesArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: what i have asked.. what you posted? i want similar category count

Comment: @learn_swift You question was regarding how to delete a tableView cell when from a list of options?